# Ошибка декодирования заполнения OAEP RSA

Tags: c#, rsa

В принципе проблема решена, но так как считывание происходит поблочно, размер блока сильно влияет на скорость. С шифрованием все гуд. Метод для шифрования:

```
public bool Encrypt_RSA_File(string inputFile, string outFile, string fileext, int keySize, string xmLstring)
    {
        try
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
            rsa.FromXmlString(xmLstring);
            using (var fstreamIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var fstreamOut = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fstreamOut))
            {
                byte[] extbytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileext);
                byte[] extencrypted = rsa.Encrypt(extbytes, true);
                bw.Write(extencrypted, 0, extencrypted.Length);

                byte[] buf = new byte[64];
                byte[] temp = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFile);
                _currentMaxProg = temp.Length;

                for (; ; )
                {
                    if (_cancelled)
                    {
                        _currentProg = 0;
                        _currentMaxProg = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                    int bytesRead = fstreamIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    _currentProg += bytesRead;
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    byte[] encrypted = bytesRead == buf.Length ? rsa.Encrypt(buf, true) : rsa.Encrypt(buf.Take(bytesRead).ToArray(), true);
                    fstreamOut.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                    if (CurrentProgressChanged != null) CurrentProgressChanged(_currentProg);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                _currentProg = 0;
                _currentMaxProg = 0;
                if (CurrentProgressChanged != null) CurrentProgressChanged(_currentProg);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return false; }
    }
```

бинарным писателем пишем в выходной файл расширение исходного файла в зашифрованном виде - работает.

сам метод вызывается так:

```
 if (_crypter.Encrypt_RSA_File(path, path.Replace(fileext, ".crypt"), fileext, _view.RsAstrength, _xmLstring))
                {
                    _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog("шифрование файла " + path + " завершилось успешно");
                    _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog(string.Concat("файл сохранен как ", path.Replace(fileext, ".crypt")));
                }
                else
                {
                    _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog("операция прервана. Файл" + path + " не обработан.");
                    _manager.Delete((T)Convert.ChangeType(path.Replace(fileext, ".crypt"), typeof(T)));
                    return;
                }
```

Теперь непосредственно о том, что под вопросом. Следующим способом

```
string fileext = _crypter.DecryptRsaExtension(path, _view.RsAstrength, _xmLstring);
            if (_crypter.Decrypt_RSA_File(path, path.Replace(".crypt", fileext), _view.RsAstrength, _xmLstring))
            {
                _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog("расшифровка файла " + path + " завершилась успешно");
                _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog(string.Concat("файл сохранен как ", path.Replace(".crypt", "")));
            }
            else
            {
                _view.LogContent += _logger.WriteToLog("операция прервана. Файл" + path + " не обработан.");
                _manager.Delete((T)Convert.ChangeType(path.Replace(".crypt", ""), typeof(T)));
                return;
            }
```

сначала выдираем и расшифровываем расширение файла и передаем его как один из параметров для расшифровки основной части зашифрованного файла. Расширение выдирается так:

```
public string DecryptRsaExtension(string path, int keySize, string xmLstring)
    {
        var fstreamIn = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buf = new byte[RsaEncFileExtSize(keySize)];
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
        rsa.FromXmlString(xmLstring);
        fstreamIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(buf, true);
        var ext = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
        return ext;
    }
```

`RsaEncFileExtSize(keySize)` нужен для того, чтобы на основе размера ключа с  которым шифровали файл определить количество байт, которые нам нужны для получения расширения. Работает очень просто:

```
private int RsaEncFileExtSize(int keySize)
    {
        int result = 0;
        switch (keySize)
        {
            case 1024: result = 128; break;
            case 2048: result = 256; break;
            case 3072: result = 384; break;
            case 4096: result = 512; break;
            case 5120: result = 640; break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Далее сам метод расшифровки:

```
public bool Decrypt_RSA_File(string encryptedFile, string decryptedFile, int keySize, string xmLstring)
    {
        try
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
            rsa.FromXmlString(xmLstring);
            using (var fstreamIn = new FileStream(encryptedFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var fstreamOut = new FileStream(decryptedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                int ext = RsaEncFileExtSize(keySize);
                byte[] buf = new byte[384];
                byte[] temp = File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedFile);

                _currentMaxProg = temp.Length;
                for (; ; )
                {
                    if (_cancelled)
                    {
                        _currentProg = 0;
                        _currentMaxProg = 0;
                        return false;
                    }

                    var bytesRead = fstreamIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    _currentProg += bytesRead;
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    if (_currentProg > ext)
                    {
                        byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(buf, true);
                        fstreamOut.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                        if (CurrentProgressChanged != null) CurrentProgressChanged(_currentProg);
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }
                }
                _currentProg = 0;
                _currentMaxProg = 0;
                if (CurrentProgressChanged != null) CurrentProgressChanged(_currentProg);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return false; }
    }
```

Если я указываю размер `buf = 384`, все работает, но оооооочень медленно. Файл, который занимает в исходном и зашифрованном виде 10 с чем-то и 30 с чем-то метров соответственно расшифровывается 10-15 минут. И да, я помню, что вместо 384 надо писать `RsaEncFileExtSize(int keySize)`, но на данный момент тестирую с ключом 3072. Если же пишу 64, 128, 192, 256, выдает ошибку декодирования заполнения OAEP на строке `byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(buf, true);`, когда `_currentProg > 384.`  Внимание вопрос: Как можно уменьшить размер считываемого блока, чтобы не было ошибки заполнения? Либо как повысить производительность для `buf=384` или `RsaEncFileExtSize(intkeySize)`?

P.S. просто решил избавиться от зашифрованных файлов с двойным расширением. Если при шифровании расширение записывать в чистом виде(без шифрования), проблема та же.
замена на `byte[] buf = new byte[ext];` где  `ext = RsaEncFileExtSize(keySize);` не решает проблемы.

Comment: Вы там тревогу оставили. Уточните, чем модератор может вам помочь с этим вопросом?

Comment: дело в том, что не уверен в том, что удалил свой ответ и вопрос все еще открыт, так как когда захожу вижу свой ответ. Он неверный - поспешил второй раз. Хотел, чтобы модераторы проверили.

Comment: Вопрос не удален и все еще открыт. Ответ удален.